# Framework in Java: correct to expose implementation directly vs interface?

Tags: java, interface

I have seen several answers to whether all Java classes should implement interfaces or not. Opinions differ and personally I do not see the benefit of writing an interface if I am certain that there will be only one implementation for it.

In this case, however, this particular class is part of a framework and will be used by others. Is it appropriate to let users use the implementation directly or should I create an interface for it? Right now I'm controlling users' access to methods through public/private.

Classes such as `String` do not implement an interface and we use them directly. On the other hand, that code is quite old and perhaps things have changed since then and it wasn't updated in order to avoid breaking something.

Comment: It depends.  Defining a well documented interface means that the users of the framework are not exposed to the inner workings, which they may be tempted to circumvent and take control them selves.  If the only way into an API is via the interface, you protect the framework.  It also means that should you want to, you change the underlying implementation of the framework (to work with a different database or service) without adversely effecting the users of the frame work.  Never assume things won't change.  They have a very bad habit of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: It's generally a good idea not to be dogmatic about *anything*.

Think of it this way: When you're building a house, you shouldn't decide on a single kind of nail you're going to use - you can't use nails for everything, and they were purposely designed in different sizes to let you pick the kind that best fits your particular needs and materials when you need them.

So how and when to use an interface depends entirely on the type, structure and intended use of your class. You certainly won't have to always use one interface per class - especially not if you value the SRP and keep your classes small and restricted to a single responsibility. But at times you may want to do so, and sometimes you'll even find good reasons to implement more than one interface in the same class.

The important thing about interfaces is that you use them to *abstract* from a specific implementation, regardless of how many different implementations you're going to have. There are plenty of possible reasons for doing this, e.g. letting someone else handle instantiation for you (such as an application server; this approach its often used for frameworks, btw), decoupling components to improve dependency management, not to forget unit testing (it's much easier to mock an object, when your code has only references to an interface), etc. It is not something that should be decided based on the number of times an API will be implemented, but on choosing the best way to keep your code cleanly structured, loosely coupled and readable.

To decide what to do, start by learning more about the house you're building: Check out the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and try to apply those well - you'll know a lot more about abstractions and interfaces, and what they should be used for. They won't have an answer to everything, either, but from there on out you can start making your own observations, and possibly invent your own principles, to deal with what they don't cover. They're definitely a good place to get started.

Answer (score 1):

If you control how the instances are created, then it doesn't matter what you publish. If you do not control how the instances are created, then it matters quite a bit.

Clients can not create interfaces, they can only create concrete objects that implement them.

However, if the instances are always created through some mechanism you control (a factory, a lookup, injection, whatever), then most of the time the distinction between an interface, abstract, or concrete class is simply a non-issue.

If the client is expected to extend the instance, then that has impact as well. You can extend an interface, but not in the same way you can extend a normal class. The mechanics and ramifications are a bit different.

In the end, most of the time, a concrete class can be converted in to an interface with no one being the wiser, unless they're creating their own instances.